# ArcGIS Pro Dissolve Boundaries Summary Fields

Tags: arcgis-pro

I'm using the dissolve boundaries tool to merge adjacent polygons. I want to calculate summary statistics on several fields for each of the output polygons. However, when I specify a summary field the output always has the same value for every single polygon (as though the statistics were calculated for a single multi-part feature, even though I have unchecked the 'create multi-part' option).

Using dissolve instead of dissolve boundaries seems to do the same thing. Is there any way to get the tool do what I want without writing some custom script?

EDIT: Updated example screenshots w/ attribute tables as requested

Before dissolve boundaries: Here, my goal is to dissolve these six records into two polygons (NOT a multipart polygon), and calculate the mean value of the "Brghtns" field independently for each. For example, the two records highlighted in blue should be dissolved into a single polygon with a average "Brghtns" value of ~98.05, and the four unhighlighted records should form a second polygon with average "Brghtn" value of ~81.
[image]

After dissolve boundaries. The geometries have done exactly what I want, but "Mean_Brghtns" value is the same for both, and it has been calculated as the mean value for ALL input polys in the input layer. 
[image]
*Note: there are many more records in the input FC than the ones being displayed in the attribute table for this example, hence the odd value of -6.66E21*

Comment: Verify they are not multi-part by using the select tool and clicking on a polygon, if they all light up then you have a multipart feature. You could try using the multi-to-single part tool to explode them out into separate polygons?

Comment: They are not multi-part, I have verified. However, the values summarized  attributes are 1) identical for each feature, and 2) the same as  those of the single multi-part feature that results if I *do* run the tool w/ the 'create multipart' option checked.

Comment: Are the coordinate systems of the datasets the same?

Comment: Only one input dataset

Comment: I think you need to edit your question and show a screen shot of the attribute table and the data it has and how you are running the tool.

Comment: Edited, hope that provides some clarity

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is down to you not setting the dissolve field. Currently you set *summary* field but not the *dissolve* field. So at the moment everything is included in the dissolve even though you set the output to not be multi-part. Hence the output all having the same mean value.

What you need to do is add a new field lets call it "group" and then select up the polygons that you want to dissolve into a single group and set them as 1, then go to next set of polygons, select them and set them as 2  and so on. Then you can use  the group field to be your dissolve by field.

Now you may have zillions of polygons and manually setting a group number is not feasible. I would just use the dissolve tool, to dissolve into single parts, create a numeric field and populate then do a spatial join to pass back the group number to the individual polygons and then you can run the dissolve boundaries tool successfully meaning the values.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, this sound reasonable and will give it a shot.